# Are there any electrically heated winter gloves?

Tags: clothing, winter

Every winter in -30C my fingers freeze. My warmest military grade gloves don't solve the problem. I wonder if electrically heated gloves will do a better job of keeping my hands warm, but haven't found any. Do they exist? If so, what qualities should I look for when choosing a type?

Comment: A quick Google search found this: http://www.thewarmingstore.com/heated-gloves.html

Comment: "warmest military grade gloves" doesn't sound particularly warm to me (although I don't know what you actually have).  If your question was about cold weather systems in general, I might suggest down or Primaloft mittens.

Comment: I think a simple [Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=electric+gloves&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=5tkVVqOBFsGV8Qfi77agCg#safe=off&q=electric+gloves) could have answered this question.

Comment: Frankly, "military grade" for a lot of stuff doesn't mean that it's all that great. What gloves are you using?

Comment: Shopping request?

Comment: @Wills I don't think this is a shopping question, the best answer should highlight the availability of electric gloves for motorcycle and snowmobile where there is a lot of available energy, and the difficulty of packing electrical power to keep gloves (or socks) warm for a full day. As well as the tendency for the heating elements to break in heavy use on hands and feet.

Comment: @JamesJenkins The answer then is simply yes, those gloves exist.

Comment: @AllanL Yes they exist, no you don't need them.  You need [these](http://blackdiamondequipment.com/en/ski-gloves/absolute-mitt-BD801681_cfg.html) I have used them in -40C and hands stayed warm.  From what I know military gear is only mediocre and there are many many fake products marketed as "Military Grade" that are just simple polyester fibre insulation.

Comment: @AllanL Sorry if my comment doesn't address the fact that you may need these for medical reasons such as poor circulation...

Comment: Chemical packs are more common. A battery is not a weight-efficient way to carry around stored energy. This is why it was historically so much easier to build gas-powered cars than electric cars.

Comment: My pleasure! I didn't realize this was a duplicate. I hope you found useful advice at the other question!

Answer (score 8):

They're not cheap, but they exist:

http://www.rei.com/product/871649/outdoor-research-stormtracker-heated-gloves

http://www.outdoorresearch.com/en/stormtracker-heated-gloves.html